# how to pass a list as argument in a function in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following string `a = "1.MATCHES_$TEXT$$STRING"`

I want to create a function which at some point calls the `split` function. My function looks like this:

```
def myfunction(x,splt,sel_nr,col=False):
    if(not col):   
         return(x.split(splt)[sel_nr]
```

My question is that this: `a.split('$')[0:2]` works, but this:

`myfunction(x=a,splt='$',sel_nr=[0:2],col=False)` does not and I do not understand why.

I also tried:

```
def myfunction(x,splt,*sel_nr,col=False):
    if(not col):   
         return(x.split(splt)[sel_nr]
```

but it still does not work

I am using python 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this! `sel_nr` is invalid, you can do it with follow way!

```
def myfunction(x,splt,start, end,col=False):
     if not col:   
          return(x.split(splt)[start: end])

myfunction(x=a,splt='$',start=1, end=3,col=False)
```